# Link WorkItem to Label

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-workitem

Is there a way to Link a WorkItem to a Label. Under "All Links" when I create a new WorkItem in Visual Studio I can select many diffrent Link Types, like Changeset, VersionedItem, etc, but theres no type for Label.

The reason why I want to do it is, that I label my releases (like Version 1.0, Version 1.1) and I want to associate a Bug to a specific version of my software.

Isn´t it support to link a WorkItem to a Label or how should I associate a Bug to a version of my software?

**Update:**
I´m following the Single Team Branching Model (one Dev and one Main branch) documented in the [Visual Studio TFS Branching Guide 2010](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot link to a label. However you can achieve your goal in other ways.

First of all, I suggest to use branching instead of labelling to keep track of multiple released versions. In my opninion using branches is a better mechanism then labelling. See also the [branching guidance](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/) on codeplex

To link your bug to a version of your software, use the Iteration Path in the work item. This field is exactly for that purpose.

Comment: +1 Thanks for answering: I´ve read the branching guidance and i´m following the SingleTeamBranchingModel with one Dev and one Main branch. But in this model they are applying labels for version releases. I think i have to go with the IterationPath.

Answer (score 2):

Using iteration path field is one option and it gives you the ability to track a work item between versions.
But if you want higher resolution, there is another way:
Team Build marks source code with a label before every build. The bug item type in CMMI project template contains fields called "Found In" and "Fixed In". In these fields you can select from build labels.
Use of these fields allow you to mark any work item with two specific builds. One for when it was found and one for when it was fixed.
Additionally Team Build updates "Fixed In" field of every work item with the label of the build, after the build completes successfully and all tests are ran without a problem.
If you don't have these fields on your work item type, you can always add them using the work item template editor that comes with TFS Power Tools.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer. I´ll give TFS Power Tools a try and check if editing the templates, solves my question.